# Bootstrap table won't resize by itself when resizing window

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

If we click on a button, a div expends to col-md-8 to col-md-12. Within this div, we have a table.table.table-responsive managed by Bootstrap.

The table size/merging tds won't refresh by themselves when resizing the window (a refresh is needed).

[It seems to be a knows issue](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/faq/), though, nothing works for me.

When the div expands: it expands allright, but if I can make the table also expand, the content inside won't. Do you have any ideas ?

Example of what I coded [available in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/830jpzf9/).

I'll really appreciate your help, thanks!

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.16.0/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">

<div id="table-wrapper">
  <table id="table" class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
    <thead id="table-thead">
      <th>Blanai</th>
      <th>Blanai</th>
      <th>Blanai</th>
      <th>Blanai</th>
      <th>Blanai</th>
      <th>Blanai</th>
      <th>Blanai</th>
      <th>Blanai</th>
      <th>Blanai</th>
      <th>Blanai</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table-tbody">
      <td>Pounrn</td>
      <td>Pounrn</td>
      <td>Pounrn</td>
      <td>Pounrn</td>
      <td>Pounrn</td>
      <td>Pounrn</td>
      <td>Pounrn</td>
      <td>Pounrn</td>
      <td>Pounrn</td>
      <td>Pounrn</td>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.16.0/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
```

```
const resetTableView = () => {
  const tableWrapper = document.getElementById('table-wrapper');
  const thead = document.getElementById('table-thead');
  const tbody = document.getElementById('table-tbody');
  const wrapperWidth = tableWrapper.style.width;
  $(table).bootstrapTable('resetView');
  table.style.width = wrapperWidth;
  thead.style.width = wrapperWidth;
  tbody.style.width = wrapperWidth;
  console.log('table view reset ok');
};

aSpecialBtn.addEventListener("click", (() => {
  const wrapper = document.getElementById('table-wrapper-wrapper');
  const wrapperIsReduced = doesWrapperIsReduced(wrapper);

  if (wrapperIsReduced) {
    expandWrapper(wrapper); // calls resetTableView();
  } else {
    reduceWrapper(wrapper); // calls resetTableView();
  } 
  return resetTableView();
}));
document.addEventListener("keypress", e => {
  if (e.key == 'Enter') {
    resetTableView();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to try use `@media` to make it responsive , because this issue is common now, so 
try to add `{sm-md-lg-xl}` like this `.table-responsive{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl}`, make your table `overflow-Y:auto;` , and overriding bootstrap classes

reference :-  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/content/tables/

Comment: Thanks for your help, much appreciated! Unfortunately, it doesn't work... I figured out how to expend the table, but it's content stays the same even if I manually resetView of bootstrapTable.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do it was to:

- Remove .table-responsive: this way, the table content would by itself take all the available space.
- Apply *max-width: 100%* and *overflow-y: auto* to the table's wrapper.

I loose the ability to have a + button that displays content non available on first sight, since with this solution we need to scroll horizontally to see all the table.